# How to hide foreign key elements from tables in SQL Developer Data Modeler?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship, oracle-sql-data-modeler

For example, I have two tables `UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT` and `PHYSICAL_QUANTITY`. `PHYSICAL_QUANTITY` has a field what represents foreign key of `UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT` table. When i add this relationship, `PHYSICAL_QUANTITY_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT_FK` at `PHYSICAL_QUANTITY` table is shown. How can i hide this element (not relationship) from table?
[image]

There is way to hide primary key elements from table. Just Right-click at table -> select "Show / Hide elements" -> select elements that must be hidden and click "OK".

[image]

But `PHYSICAL_QUANTITY_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT_FK` element is not shown there.
Why? And is there a way to hide `PHYSICAL_QUANTITY_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT_FK` element from table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the elements that you need to be shown by right clicking on the diagram (not in the tables), and selecting the ones you need in **View Details**

[image]